# Match any horizontal whitespace characters at the start of each line in multiline strings in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace all empty spaces on the beginning of all new lines. I have two regex replacements:

```
$txt = preg_replace("/^　+/m", '', $txt);
$txt = preg_replace("/^[^\S\r\n]+/m", '', $txt);
```

Each of them matches different kinds of empty spaces. However, there may be chances that both of the empty spaces exist and in different orders, so I want to match occurences of all of them at the beginning of new lines. How can I do that?

**NOTE**: The first regex matches an *ideographic space*, `\u3000` char, which is only possible to check in the [question raw body](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ce6b44bb-a5fc-4d04-9913-3c4b69f4520f/view-source) (SO rendering is not doing the right job here). The second regex matches only ASCII whitespace chars other than LF and CR. [**Here is a demo**](https://3v4l.org/dcANV) proving the second regex does not match what the first regex matches.

Comment: You only need `^\h+`.

Comment: @revo, thanks, but when I am using ^\h+, all the content in $txt get replaced. Any idea why?

Comment: Try `"/^\h+/mu"`. Your first regex matches an ideographic space, so you deal with Unicode texts, and `u` modifier might be handy here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew @revo Oh I mistyped something. Adding the `u` does work, thanks!

Comment: FYI your second regex `^[^\S\r\n]+` includes what first regex matches. It means the second regex does all you want, requiring no `u` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to remove any horizontal whitespace from a Unicode string you need  to use

- `\h` [regex escape](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) (*"any horizontal whitespace character (since PHP 5.2.4)"*)
- `u` modifier (see [Pattern Modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php))

Use

```
$txt = preg_replace("/^\h+/mu", '', $txt);
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (`m` modifier makes `^` match all line start positions, not just string start position)
- `\h+` - one or more horizontal whitespaces
- `u` modifier will make sure the Unicode text is treated as a sequence of Unicode code points, not just code units, and will make all regex escapes in the pattern Unicode aware.